# Getting a white screen with my installed app in Android emulator (however works in browser)

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, adb

I am having issues getting a legacy mobile app to run in an emulator - it all seems to run in the browser without any issues but when I run the **cordova emulate** command  the app attempts to install but I always get a white screen (nothing else) & the app isn't visible to use.

I am running Cordova CLI v5.0.0 although the app was made about a year ago so was developed in an older version of Cordova.

Can anyone suggest the best ways to debug this app to find the cause of the problem & why the problem only persists when I run the emulate command but seems fine in the browser?

-- update --
I have installed the Samsung drivers to allow me to connect my OnePlusOne device to adb, and I am know using the Android Studio program to collate errors etc..

In Android studio I can see the logs (see gist below):

https://gist.github.com/gkimpson/fbde0f5a7d1017daae17

Its quite long so added it externally - any ideas why I am having problems with my app?

-- update --
This line seems to be the problem

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient﹕ file:///android_asset/www/js/app/modules/stickers/stickers.js: Line 357 : Uncaught TypeError: window.requestFileSystem is not a function
```

The code in stickers.js is below for that section..

```
if (window.isDevice) {
     window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 512, onInitFs, errorHandler);
} else {
     callback(fc);
}
```

Comment: Have you removed and re-created the android platform when you upgraded to cordova cli 5?

Comment: Just run cordova platform remove android & then re-added so its the latest version and re-run on my device but the problem persists

Comment: is the message still the same? I suggest you also remove and reinstall all the plugins (with the new ids), and don't forget to add the white list plugin. (I had to delete the plugins folder to completly uninstall all plugins)

Comment: Hmm never heard of the whitelist plugin - can you recommend the best way to add this? Will remove the plugins folder now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what I had to do when I migrated from cordova 3.6 to cordova 5.

But first, I suggest you a little reading :

[Cordova Android 4 release notes](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html)

[Plugins switch to npm](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html)

[The white list plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) And in addition [the CSP documentation](http://content-security-policy.com/)

To sum-up, the security has changed in cordova, if you don't add the white list plugin your app will have no network access, and the plugins are now installed via npm instead of via git.

So what I did (a little bit hardcore maybe):

- delete completly the platforms/android folder
- delete the plugins folder (maybe before cordova plugins list if you don't have the list somewhere)
- reinstall the plugins with the new name (most of external plugins haven't changed name, but all cordova plugins have) for example cordova-plugin-camera replaces org.apache.cordova.camera
- add the white list plugin and configure it (or if you're not concerned about security, install the white list-legacy plugin which should work as previous versions)
- add the android platform

and you can run `cordova plugin save` and `cordova platform save`to have all your plugins and platforms saved in config.xml

Comment: Brilliant - I added the new plugins added the whitelist mod to my config.xml and it shows the screen! thanks