# Add File and FileTransfer Cordova Plugin for v3.4.0

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a project started with cordova v3.4 and now I want to add File and FileTransfer to upload file to server (I use Camera plugin so)
I try to upgrade cordova to v4.1.1 and now can upload file but all jquery.ajax funtions used in js file can not connect and through timeout exdeption

```
jQuery.ajax({       
    type: "POST",
    url: "MYURL",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(result) {
    //SOME CODE
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, message) {
    //SOME CODE
    },
    timeout: 14000
});
```

### I think that need some permissions for new cordova

I use: Cordova 4.1.1
    "cordova-plugin-file": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "2.1.0"

Comment: Where do you test the app? On Android? If so the URL endpoints might be blocked by default.

Comment: I use "Genymotion" with android 4.2.2. before change all ajax request worked fine. This is important that file upload work now and my ajax kiss! error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
After upgrade Cordova to version higher than 4, You should add Whitelist plugin so.

[Cordova Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

Note 1: To sum-up, the security has changed in cordova, if you don't add the white list plugin your app will have no network access, and the plugins are now installed via npm instead of via git. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321490/getting-a-white-screen-with-my-installed-app-in-android-emulator-however-works))